# O Firemonkey consegue utilizar minha GPU e o Direct2D?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, windows-10, firemonkey

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento de um jogo para Windows 10 e gostaria de saber se o Firemonkey consegue utilizar a minha GPU sem qualquer configuração extra.

Ouvi "boatos" de que na verdade o Firemonkey consegue utilizar automaticamente o Direct2D, se disponível, para suas tarefas de renderização rotineiras.

Cheguei a essa questão pois comecei tentando utilizar (sem muito sucesso) o cabeçalho WinAPI.D2D1 que vem com o RAD Studio.

Então, como funciona o firemonkey por baixo dos panos? Consegue ele utilizar o DirectX e a GPU dedicada sem qualquer configuração extra? Seria relevante a diferença de performance entre o Firemonkey e o DirectX "cru" para o desenvolvimento de jogos?